# plot emoji font family not rendering the same in rstudio image pane and jpeg()

Tags: r, plot, emoji

I am using `emojifont` library in rstudio. I do not have `EmojiOne.ttf` installed on my own computer. I work on Ubuntu 16.04.
If I plot directly the following code:

```
library(emojifont)

x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, cex=0)
text(x, y, labels=emoji('cow'), cex=1.5, col='steelblue', family='EmojiOne')
```

I get this figure in the rstudio figure pane:
[image: rstudio_output]

But, if I save it directly with `png()` or `jpeg()` (even with `x11()`), emoji displayed are different:

```
jpeg()
plot(x, y, cex=0)
text(x, y, labels=emoji('cow'), cex=4, col='steelblue', family='EmojiOne')
dev.off()

png()
plot(x, y, cex=0)
text(x, y, labels=emoji('cow'), cex=4, col='steelblue', family='EmojiOne')
dev.off()

x11()
plot(x, y, cex=0)
text(x, y, labels=emoji('cow'), cex=4, col='steelblue', family='EmojiOne')
```

[image: jpg or png output]

The good result from EmojiOne font, according to examples of library `emojifont` is the one from the `jpeg` output. This means that rstudio uses its own font.

I am interested in this rstudio family font, what is this font family ?
Why isn't it the same than `jpeg()` output ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a known issue...
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html#limitation

> Limitation
>
> RStudio using a different way to open graphics device and showtext is currently incompatible with it.
>
> Since emojifont use showtext as backend to parse emoji font, it also incompatible with RStudio.
>
> The solution is to manually open a window by calling X11() in Linux, quartz() in Mac or windows() in Windows, and create plots on top of that, instead of the built-in device offered by RStudio.

But I still do not know where rstudio found the font family...